# Some confuse in spectral sequence and its calculate

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, spectral-sequences

We have the Leray's theorem:
Let $\pi:E\longrightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle with fiber $F$ over a simply connected base space $B$. Assume that in every dimension $n$, $H^{\ast}(F)$ is of finite rank and free. Then there exist a spectral sequence $\left\{(E_r,d_r)\right\}$ with
$$
E_2^{p,q}=H^{p}(B)\otimes H^{q}(F)
$$
and a filtration $\left\{D_i\right\}$ on $H^{\ast}(E)$ s.t.
$$
E_{\infty}=\bigoplus_{p,q}{E_{\infty}^{p,q}}\simeq GH^{\ast}\left( E \right) 
$$
i.e there is a filtration $\left\{D_i\cap H^n\right\}$ on $H^{n}:=H^{n}(E)$ s.t.
$$
H^n=D_0\cap \underset{E_{\infty}^{0,n}}{\underbrace{H^n\supset D_1}}\cap \underset{E_{\infty}^{1,n-1}}{\underbrace{H^n\supset D_2}}\cap \underset{E_{\infty}^{2,n-2}}{\underbrace{H^n\supset \cdots }}
$$
**What confuses me is why the quotient $\frac{D_p\cap H^n}{D_{p+1}\cap H^n}=E_{\infty}^{p,n-p}
$**

Another thing that puzzles me is that when we use Leray's theorem to calculate the cohomology of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$, the stable page $E_{\infty}=E_3$ looks like
[image]

**When $p\geqslant 5$, the cohomology of $H^{\ast}(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2)$ are all trivial, I don't know how can we attact with it. The concept of spectral sequence makes me feel a cloud of fog. Do we have any good ways to understand it in geometric topology?**

I would be grateful if you could help me！

Comment: Have you seen the details in the construction of the spectral sequence?  The identification of the $E_\infty$ page with the associated graded is not difficult, but requires some bookkeeping.  Also, be clear about the fibration in the second half of your question.  Assuming it's $S^1 \to S^5 \to \mathbb{C}P^2$, note that $H^5(S^5) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so there must be something in the $(p,q) = (4,1)$ box since that's the only nonzero contribution to degree 5.  Multiplicativity implies there is something in the $(4,0)$ box, which must be killed by something in the $(2,1)$ box, etc.